# Not able to install my application on other Android devices

Tags: android, deployment, android-studio, apk

I have made an Android app using AndroidStudio and want to test it on different phones. I have generated the signed apk (release version) and I could successfully install the apk on my device (Nexus 5).

Then I tried to install the same apk on a Nexus 4 but it throws an error after the installation that the package installer has stopped.

Here is what my manifest file looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:permission="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/endecrypt_ico"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".PostSubmission"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_post_submission"
        android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.psimit.encrypt.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

I am not able to understand where the problem lies. Since the app works when installed via the debugger and also using the apk on my phone, I am tempted to think if I need to do something more for compatibility across Nexus 4 and Nexus 5 during the generation of the signed apk.

I would quite appreciate some pointers if someone has encountered this problem earlier. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="minver"
        android:targetSdkVersion="targetver" />` ??

Comment: What is your minimum SDK version? Make sure it's below or equals the SDK version the Nexus 4 has to be able to install it.

Comment: are you using Android Studio ?

Comment: @HugoGresse "I have made an Android app using AndroidStudio". Pretty sure, yes.

Comment: The minimum SDK version is 16 and the target version is 22. I have already checked that Nexus 4 is covered with this setting.

Comment: @Cmux have you tried my answer ? if so comment on it if it's correct or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a really strange issue you have. Maybe you're doing things wrong.

The **permissions** should be at the root of the manifest tag :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application>

        <activity
            ...
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I'll check out if this works. However, even if *permissions* within the application tag is causing the problem, it doesn't explain why the apk is installed correctly on Nexus 5.

Comment: Removing the **permissions** from the application tag worked for me. Since my app does not need any other permissions, I have not used any `<uses-permission/>` tag at all.